# How to test Cloud Functions with Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to test cloud functions function.
But, in testing(`npm run test`) I got this error.

Why did I get this error? how to fix it?

```
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
at Object.join (path.js:1218:7)
at database (node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore.js:36:45)
at Object.document (node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore.js:44:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.ts:6:21)
at Object.loadTypeScript (node_modules/espower-typescript/index.js:23:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Context.before (test/initialize-pair.ts:19:23)
```

This is my index.ts.
It is working as a real cloud functions function.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
export const aFunc = functions.firestore.document('/users/{uid}').onUpdate(() => { console.log('called')});
```

thanks

Comment: What is `npm run test` supposed to do?  That's not a normal script for a Cloud Functions for Firebase setup.

Comment: Oh, I just found `test` in `functions/packages.json`.   What is the normal script for local testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're running `npm run test` without understanding what your particular test script is supposed to actually do.  There isn't an npm script provided by the Firebase CLI for testing functions automatically.

If you want to do unit testing of your functions, [read the advice in the documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing).

If you want to use the local emulator to manually simulate events to your function, [read the documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator).